# BT arise Joomla Template

Tags: templates, joomla

I have installed Joomla 2.5 in my system with all those necessary configuration. I downloaded and installed bt-arise-unzip-me-first(1).zip template.

The error which i found is JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file.

Can any one please find me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you unzip your files to upload the right one ? Look at the "unzip-me-first" text in the filename.

Comment: yes, i did it. Please look at the error after uploading this template "JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file"

Comment: Typically you see those errors when you are trying to install an invalid template (an previous version of joomla maybe) or there is no template at all in that file.